# python mechanize follow_link fails

Tags: python, hyperlink, mechanize

I'm trying to access search results on the NCBI Images search page (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/images) in a script.  I want to feed it a search term, report on all of the results, and then move on to the next search term.  To do this I need to get to results pages after the first page, so I'm trying to use python mechanize to do it:

```
import mechanize
browser=mechanize.Browser()
page1=browser.open('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/images?term=drug')
a=browser.links(text_regex='Next')
nextlink=a.next()
page2=browser.follow_link(nextlink)
```

This just gives me back the first page of search results again (in variable page2).  What am I doing wrong, and how can I get to that second page and beyond?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately that page uses Javascript to POST 2459 bytes of form variables to the server, just to navigate to a subsequent page.  Here are a few of the variables (I count 38 vars in total):

```
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.ImagesDb.Images_SearchBar.Term=drug
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.ImagesDb.Images_SearchBar.CurrDb=images
EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.ImagesDb.Images_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage=2
```

You'll need to construct a POST request to the server containing some or all of these variables. Luckily if you get it working for page 2 you can simply increment `CurrPage` and send another POST to get each subsequent page of results (no need to extract links).

**Update** - That site is a total pain-in-the-ass, but here is a POST-based scrape of the 2-N pages. Set `MAX_PAGE` to the highest page number + 1.  The script will produce files like `file_000003.html`.

**Note**: Before you use it, you need to replace `POSTDATA` with the [contents of this paste blob](http://pastebin.com/UfejW3G0) (it expires in 1 month). It's just the body a POST request as captured by Firebug, which I use to seed the correct params:

```
import cookielib
import json
import mechanize
import sys
import urllib
import urlparse

MAX_PAGE = 6
TERM = 'drug'
DEBUG = False

base_url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/images?term=' + TERM
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)
browser.set_debug_http(DEBUG)
browser.set_debug_responses(DEBUG)
cjar = cookielib.CookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cjar)

# make first GET request. this will populate the cookie
res = browser.open(base_url)

def write(num, data):
    with open('file_%06d.html' % num, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(data)

def encode(kvs):
    res = []
    for key, vals in kvs.iteritems():
        if isinstance(vals, list):
            for v in vals:
                res.append('%s=%s' % (key, urllib.quote(v)))
        else:
            res.append('%s=%s' % (key, urllib.quote(vals)))
    return '&'.join(res)

write(1, res.read())

# set this var equal to the contents of this: http://pastebin.com/UfejW3G0
POSTDATA = '''<post data>'''

# parse the embedded json vars into POST parameters
PREFIX1 = 'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.ImagesDb.'
PREFIX2 = 'EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector.'
params = dict((k, v[0]) for k, v in urlparse.parse_qs(POSTDATA).iteritems())

base_url = 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/images'
for page in range(2, MAX_PAGE):
    params[PREFIX1 + 'Images_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.CurrPage'] = str(page)
    params[PREFIX1 + 'Images_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager.cPage'] = [str(page-1)]*2

    data = encode(params)
    req = mechanize.Request(base_url, data)
    cjar.add_cookie_header(req)
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    req.add_header('Referer', base_url)
    res = browser.open(req)

    write(page, res.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't know any Javascript, so can I use some POST capability provided by mechanize or do I need to do something in Javascript?

Comment: By the way I have tried previously using wget and curl with POST data for those variables, and got basically the same behavior: always just getting the first page of results, no matter what CurrPage number I passed.  It's perplexing.

Comment: You can submit a POST from mechanize. The site you're trying to scrape is doing some crazy stuff, so it may be a bit involved to work out exactly which variables need to be submitted. I'll update my answer with an example of doing a POST with mechanize, in case that helps.